# GlassFish 4.0 / Jersey 2.0 - NoClassDefFoundError for JsonStructureBodyReader

Tags: json, glassfish, glassfish-4, jersey-2.0

I'm using GlassFish 4.0 R89 on my dev system, working with JAX-RS. Simple calls work, so I can get a serialized object, represented in XML. I had to install that on the machine of a guy who will also be involved in the coding process, and I also tried that on my notebook - and I'm getting the same result - a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown for the class JsonStructureBodyReader (although I'm not even using JSON, tried that, the server definitely returns XML with correct headers for the content-type).

I thought I might have imported a project incorrectly, but after a comparison of the files in the working and the non-working version, I realized that there doesn't seem to be a difference that could be responsible for that (the projects are more or less equal on both machines).

I thought maybe there's a problem with the GF version, so I checked that, but both installations are R89. However: The jars in the GFs modules/ directory seem to be different, especially when doing a binary comparison.

Has anyone experienced that problem before?

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/json/jaxrs/JsonStructureBodyReader
at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonp.JsonProcessingFeature.configure(JsonProcessingFeature.java:69)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:617)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:558)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:361)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:84)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:116)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:113)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValue.get(Values.java:275)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:667)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:169)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:644)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:375)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:275)
at my.application.client.webservice.data.IssueClient.getIssues(IssueClient.java:50)
at my.application.client.webservice.data.IssueClient.getIssues(IssueClient.java:30)
at my.application.client.modules.issuetracker.IssueTracker.getTableData(IssueTracker.java:182)
at my.application.client.modules.issuetracker.IssueTracker.drawComponents(IssueTracker.java:80)
at my.application.client.modules.issuetracker.IssueTracker.<init>(IssueTracker.java:59)
at my.application.client.actions.ShowIssueTrackerAction.fire(ShowIssueTrackerAction.java:37)
at my.application.client.gui.PVAppMenu$2.actionPerformed(PVAppMenu.java:49)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not using JSON ([JSON Processing](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.json-p) library) then you should remove `jersey-media-json-processing` module from the classpath of your client (which seems to be outside of GF). This module depends on `jsonp-jaxrs.jar` (+ `javax.json.jar`, `javax.json-api.jar`) which contains the `JsonStructureBodyReader`. The thing is that everytime the `jersey-media-json-processing` module is on a classpath Jersey tries to register JSON Processing providers via [Auto-Discoverable](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable) mechanism. This means that in case of missing dependencies one would encounter an exteption similar to yours.

Comment: Found it, definitely a dependency issue I did not see - thanks alot for the answer, that was really helpful!

Comment: In my case I encountered this exception when trying to run the Vogella REST tutorial. Thanks to Michael's answer I just added jsonp-jaxrs.jar into my classpath and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the glassfish library from build path in eclipse. Then do add external jars,  and add all the jars from the following folders in glassfish4 directory.

1. C:\glassfish4\glassfish\modules
2. C:\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\endorsed
3. C:\glassfish4\mq\lib

Here's the client code I used to write REST client using JAX RS

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        String name = client.target("http://localhost:9999/MyResourceRestfulService/myresources/myresource")
          .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
          .get(String.class);

        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me, although GF 4.1 no longer has a `/mq` sub dir and I had to skip that part of the instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Glassfish 4.x as server and its libraries. You have to add 
javax.son.jar
jsonp-jaxrs.jar

Both libraries are located in \glassfish\modules

Comment: thanks a lot Man, why Eclipse did not import these jars ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JUNIT test with MAVEN just add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonp-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml