# running a junit test method to interact with a JAX-RS Service - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, junit, jax-rs

I have implemented and deployed a JAX-RS Service, it's up and running now. I have created a class that has ONE method that test the service methods (POST, GET, POST), the problem is that I don't how to run this test within Eclipse.

Test class: JAX-RS 2.0 Client

```
public class CustomerResourceTest {
@Test
public void testCustomerResource() throws Exception {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    try {
        System.out.println("*** Create a new Customer ***");

        String xml = "<customer>" + "<first-name>Bill</first-name>" + "<last-name>Burke</last-name>"
                + "<street>256 Clarendon Street</street>" + "<city>Boston</city>" + "<state>MA</state>"
                + "<zip>02115</zip>" + "<country>USA</country>" + "</customer>";

        Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/jax-rs/services/customers").request()
                .post(Entity.xml(xml));
        if (response.getStatus() != 201)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create");
        String location = response.getLocation().toString();
        System.out.println("Location: " + location);
        response.close();

        System.out.println("*** GET Created Customer **");
        String customer = client.target(location).request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println(customer);

        String updateCustomer = "<customer>" + "<first-name>William</first-name>" + "<last-name>Burke</last-name>"
                + "<street>256 Clarendon Street</street>" + "<city>Boston</city>" + "<state>MA</state>"
                + "<zip>02115</zip>" + "<country>USA</country>" + "</customer>";
        response = client.target(location).request().put(Entity.xml(updateCustomer));
        if (response.getStatus() != 204)
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to update");
        response.close();
        System.out.println("**** After Update ***");
        customer = client.target(location).request().get(String.class);
        System.out.println(customer);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception, when I run: Eclipse run as -> Junit test

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/json/jaxrs/JsonStructureBodyReader
at org.glassfish.jersey.jsonp.JsonProcessingFeature.configure(JsonProcessingFeature.java:68)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:714)
at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:644)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.configureMetaProviders(ClientConfig.java:372)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:405)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:90)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:122)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:733)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:135)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:105)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:101)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at ch3.pt1.test.CustomerResourceTest.testCustomerResource(CustomerResourceTest.java:26)
```

as I said Glassfish is up and running and the application (project) is deolpoyed successfully. I just don't know how to run the test method. I have tried to put the method in main(String[] args) and remove the @Test but it still give ann exception. I need a way how to run the method to test the service.

Note: this application is from chapter 3 in **RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0, 2nd Edition**, I have successfully run the test using the book method which use maven (no IDE, just cmd). but I want to test this from Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18334053/346899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Eclipse did not import this jar from Glassfish glassfish4.1.1\glassfish\modules\ **jsonp-jaxrs.jar** so I add it and re-run the test and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html. You need to inherit from JerseyTest, and specify the container you want to use.

Comment: I use Glassfish 4.1.1, and Jersey is the Reference Implementation, but Eclipse suggest JerseyClient, JerseyClientBuilder, JerseyWebTarget. but no JerseyTest. I'm sorry did I miss something ?